# unkown option natbibapa for package apacite

Tags: natbib

I have a problem with `natbibapa` for package `apacite`. I Have the following text

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{multiCol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pictexwd,dcpic}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xtocinc}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

When I run this code there is a message that,

> Unkown option `natbibapa` for package `apacite`

This is the first time where I use `natbib` package. I did not download any package from the Internet regarding to `natbib`. I only add the following sentence to LaTeX:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

I feel that in order `natbib` package working requires a document downloading from Internet.

Could you please help me in this problem?

Comment: if i would like to updated tex live, how i did this?

Comment: see http://www.tug.org/texlive/. If you are using the version preinstalled with a Linux, be sure of remove all the `texlive`packages).

Comment: could you please explain how to update the latex ?

Comment: i have Miktex 2.4

Comment: MikTeX 2.4? That is ancient, remove it, then download and install 2.9 instead http://miktex.org/download '

Comment: @alturki, TeX Live also work well in Windows. You can try TeX Live 2013 as well as MiXTeX 2.9. But take into account that a few packages are only in in MikTeX (and others only in TeXLive).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i have downloaded Miktex and it work very well. However i am wondering if you could you help me about the style of cite. i want to cite more than one the references as (first author et al. 1999; first author et al. 2000)